mnesia data replication on centralized server
I am newbie to mnesia. As to my understanding of data replication in mnesia, it is used to make a copy of the database to each node in the cluster, so if the the master node crashed, then one of the rest of the nodes can be candidate to act as a server. This technique is useful for the decentralized servers, where, any node can act as a server if the master node crashed.
My question is, does database replication needed for the centralized servers, where, there is only one server can manage the database ?

In Mnesia there is no concept of a "master" node.
When Mnesia is started on a node, it creates a schema. To create a Mnesia cluster any node can join it by make a replicate of the schema from any other node that has joined. Once the schema has been replicate the nodes can also chose to replicate user defined tables.
When many nodes are joined like this, Mnesia will make sure there are always 3 physical copies of the data somewhere in the cluster. That is something that you normally don't control but let Mnesia manage for you. This means that when you read data, sometimes parts of the data has to be fetch from other nodes (across the network), but that is also managed for you.
The Erlang applications and the database run in the same program, which makes it a bit faster and easier to access. Normally the Mnesia database is not separated from the Erlang application as it gives no or few advantages (There could be edge cases I am not considering).
But to answer your original questions:
"My question is, does database replication needed for the centralized servers, where, there is only one server can manage the database ?"
The questions is a bit unclear to me but I think you are asking:
"Is a centralized master server needed for database replication"
The answer to that question is no, as Mnesia has no concept of a master node. All Erlang nodes that joined the Erlang cluster (meaning they all replicated the same schema) are on the same level. It is a flat hierarchy.
